# Tracking a Search that leads to a sale in GA

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

This seems really basic but i am struggling with it

We have a client who runs a travel website.

They have a few different search bars eg Flights, Hotels, Carhire.

I am trying to track the performance of each... "What % of people completed a sale that ran a Flight search." Same for Hotel, and for Car hire

Any ideas for the best way to get this info in GA?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get this information, each with their pros and cons. The options that I see immediately available are segments and goals.

**Segments** are great because they are retrospective and generally more flexible, with the ability to be changed if you find your criteria isn't quite right. You create here, and specify sessions that go through search results pages etc:
[image]

Then you can create another segment for booking confirmation page, and any other intermediary steps that you'd like to report on. The main con of segments is that you can only pull in 4 at a time, but if you have more you can pull them 4 at a time and copy+paste the data into an excel sheet or google sheet. Segments can also be pulled via the [Core Reporting Api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) and [DataStudio](https://datastudio.google.com/navigation/reporting) which makes them great for automating into dashboards.

**Goals** are cool because they pull into the default reports, and basically track sessions through a particular page, event or sequence. The main con I see and the reason is that I don't use them is that they only start tracking fro mthe time you create them , and if you change the configuration it does not impact historical data, so your data can get messed up quickly if you don't have sandbox GA views or sandbox goals for your testing before putting it into a dedicated goal slot. You can also only have 10 or 20 goals depending on your plan, so once data is tracked against that goal you can't remove or clear it.